# Inner function losing data

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is an angular 1 app.
When clicking on a button a function called "register" (in "registerController") is fired:

```
$scope.register = (account, e) => {
    $scope.preUpdate( () => {
     console.log("account.localData.amount:",account.localData.amount);
     account.data.amount = angular.copy(account.localData.amount);
     console.log("account.data.amount:",account.data.amount);
     updateAccount(account);
    });
}
```

As you can see, the function above calls another function in a main controller called "myController".
Here it is:

```
myCtrl.preUpdate = (callback, argList) => {
argList = [].concat(argList);
if(!myCtrl.isFirstInMyGroup){
    let modal = $("#modNotFirstUpdate").modal();
    modal.show();
    myCtrl.currentUpdateFunction = () => {
      callback(...argList);
    }
  } else {
    callback(...argList);
  }
 }
```

When the variable "myCtrl.isFirstInMyGroup" is true, the if statement will not be executed and the else applies.
In that case, everything works fine.
Just think about htis line in the first function:

```
console.log("account.data.amount:",account.data.amount);
```

Which in this case will print not null data.

However, when the IF above applies, things won't work.
As you can see, when if applies a modal opens up a "confirm"-button in the modal has attached the

```
ng-click="currentUpdateFunction"
```

Without passing any argument (should it?).

When I click on the confirm button in the modal, then the inner "currentUpdateFunction" inside "preUpdate" fires.
However, at that point the console-log will only print null values.

It looks like data gets lost when arriving in the inner function. Is this about passing data to the inner function in some way?

Comment: oderfla : Did you try debugging your callback? try consoling the scope there and see what is it pointing to?

Comment: @SumodhNair I tried to print scope in both function. Its not empty. But Im not really sure what I should look for there?

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code step by step? E.g. with Chrome: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/

Comment: Not really familiar with step by step debugging. What I can see is that the callback still exist in the inner if-statement but its like treated like a string. For some reason. It's like I would need to execute that string in some manner.

Comment: Is `$scope.preUpdate` the same as `myCtrl.preUpdate`?

Comment: Yes. $scope.preUpdate is calling the function inside myCtrl.

Comment: `myCtrl.preUpdate` is a function with two parameters, `callback` and `argList`. The `$scope.preUpdate` is invoked with only one argument, an anonymous function. The second argument will be undefined.

Comment: @georgeawg thats true. But doesn't seem to be the issue. The problem is that the callback and its inner code is not executed or is not treated like executable stuff. Because the parameters (as described in the question) fails to be printed in the console when the callback is executed AFTER the modal AND inside the if-statement/inner function called "currentUpdateFunction".

Comment: Again: the call to the callback works inside the function "preUpdate" if NO MODAL pops up (i.e. if the first if statement is false). If the callback is executed AFTER the MODAL pops up and is closed with click on OK (i.e. inside the inner function "currentUpdateFunction") then the callback, even if not empty, executes the codes "badly" as it doesn't know anymore about the parameters inside the original function ("register"-function inside the registerCtrl).

Comment: In the if-then-else, the else clause invokes `callback`, the then clause stores `callback` in an anonymous function that it assigns to `myCtrl.currentUpdateFunction`. This code is [spaghetti](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghetti_code) city. It would be easier to understand if it returned promises instead of using callbacks.

Comment: Ok thanks for the explanation. But how would you change the code in order to make it work?